# How do I connect to an Access database over a LAN using Java?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, lan

Do you know of any good guides on how to access an Access database using Java?

I know the basics and basic SQL, but I'm thinking more about access control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static final String accessDBURLPrefix = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
    private static final String accessDBURLSuffix = ";DriverID=22;READONLY=false}";

    // Initialize the JdbcOdbc Bridge Driver
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("JdbcOdbc Bridge Driver not found!");
        }
    }

    /** Creates a Connection to a Access Database */
    public static Connection getAccessDBConnection(String filename) throws SQLException {
        filename = filename.replace('', '/').trim();
        String databaseURL = accessDBURLPrefix + filename + accessDBURLSuffix;
        return DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, "", "");
    }
```

Some useful links:

- http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-access-ms-access-database-from-jdbc/
- http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for!
Few links and some code. Cheers.

Comment: I'm getting an error java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Drivrutin f?r ODBC Microsoft Access] bad filename. I'm guessing it has to do something with this part of the code: "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=". I don't get how that part is formatted, is it supposed to automatically locate the driver? Can I just download the driver as a file and point to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using relational databases in Java, you'll need to know [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

You won't be able to do much with security using JDBC.  You'll have to build it into the application using something like [JAAS](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/) or [Spring Security](http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/reference/html/springsecurity.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can share a database over a shared drive on LAN n then add it to System DSN of other PCs and you can share access database over LAN .. Worked for me like that

I know string is old but maybe useful for someone like me i was frustrated finding a proper and easy way for sharing

Answer (score -2):

JDBC is the way to go. Google for "JDBC tutorial" + mysql, you will get all you need.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the question. I know how to use google. Thanks.

Comment: On the contrary, I did read the question. I was just giving you the right terms to search for. It is infinitely better to know what you want but not have it (for now) that to not know at all.

Comment: @jharshath: I don't see any version in the edit history of this question that mentioned MySQL.